# Pattern match to identify date format

Tags: ssis, sas, talend, informatica, pdi

My source having different date formats as shown below, And im looking for an algorithm to identify the source date pattern tried in Pentaho Data integration with select value and Fuzzy steps.

Date Column (String)
"20150210"
"20050822--"
"2014-02-May"
"20051509--"
"02-May-2014"
"2013-May-12"
"12DEC2013"
"15050815"
"May-02-2014"
"12312015"

I know that in PDI we can achieve through JS step by writing If conditions for each pattern but is not a good idea and this approach makes transformation dead when dealing with huge records, looking out for efficient way to search date pattern.

I believe this is very common issue in all ETL projects, Here Im trying to understand how enterprise vendors like SAS Data Integration, Informatica, SSIS provides easy way to handle.

Do we have any Algorithm to identify source pattern. If so which one?

The formats that are listed above are not limited.

Comment: `01-02-05` <-- What date is that? The answer is: it's entirely dependent upon the culture of the author. en-GB would translate that to `Feb  1 2005`. en-US would identify as `Jan  2 2005`. Whilst ja-JP would specify `Feb  5 2001`

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply determine a "monovalent" value as the format for any given input.

Consider all of the following formats completely valid:

- MM-dd-yy
- dd-MM-yy
- yy-MM-dd

As stated in a comment by @billinkc, what would you call `01-02-05` in that case?

If at all, your would be a solvable one only if you took a data set into account (e.g. you know that the next X rows are all from the same date format). Then you can look at it as a linear problem with some constraints that can help you determine the date format. Even then, you can't assure that you'll get a definite answer, just increase the probability that you'll have a definite answer.